# diffuse shaders cause vertical lines in 2d maps

Tags: shader, tiled, unity-game-engine

[vertical line tear in-game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0VVz.png)

Greetings! I've been using tiled and tiled2unity to design and import my maps into Unity with no problem, as long as I stick to the default tiled2Unity shader or the sprites>default shader. However, I've been trying to implement lighting into the project and thus have to change the shaders to some form of diffuse. When I change the tiled maps shaders from anything other than the two mentioned above, I get these vertical lines between tiles. I took a screenshot of the problem and have linked it to this page (the line is above and to the right of the player). The problem is especially obvious when the camera moves. I tried sprites>diffuse, standard, and mobiles variants, all with the same vertical lines appearing. But when I turn it back to sprites>default or tiled2Unity>default, the problem disappears entirely (as long as I have pixel snap enabled). What is happening? I've scoured the internet and haven't found any solutions.

Comment: Does anyone have a clue as to why this is happening? I've posted on numerous forums to no avail..

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution: using extrusion the problem disappears. Sadly I'll have to use a paid program to do this else I'll have to do every tile/sprite myself.